# Angular ng-value doesn't work with input radio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-value

I have 3 radio inputs bound to `ctrl.poiType` , where *ctrl* is the controller and *poiType* is an integer.
`ctrl.poiType` can have one of the 3 values specified by four constants
(ctrl.TYPE_TRIP, ctrl.TYPE_EVENT, ctrl.TYPE_POI).

So I've created three input radio, using ng-model and ng-value like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" 
           ng-value="ctrl.TYPE_TRIP"
           ng-model="ctrl.poiType"  
           ng-change="ctrl.alert()"/>itinerari
</label>
```

The radio should be checked if the value of `ng-model` is equal to `ng-value`, but it's not working. I don't know why.

[UPDATE]
This is the right [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r14618r7/) of the example

Comment: You need to read a bit more about angular and go through a few tutorials. You made a number of crucial mistakes and they are all listed in your browser console. Also scope variables need `$scope.foo`, not `this.foo`. Spend a bit more time on the theoretical part before starting implementing. [This](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) is a good place to start.

Comment: I made a wrong JSFiddle... now I fixed it, look the update please. I am using controllers' attributes instead of scope variables. Anyway, the initial problem it's still there

Comment: Is [that](https://jsfiddle.net/r14618r7/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes!  so I need to specify the class 'active' manually?  Isn't it automatic with radio buttons?

Comment: No, you are toggling your button which contains a radio button (2 different elements). Also selected button needs a CSS class to appear selected, while a radio-button does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem you are trying to solve is to have the selected button appear active when you click it.  Since you are using the Bootstrap styles without using the Bootstrap javascript component you will need to make this work yourself within Angular.

To make the radio button appear "checked" you must apply the active style to the label's class list.

> **Preselected options need .active**
>
> For preselected options, you must add the .active class to the input's label yourself.

The way to modify an element's class list dynamically in Angular is to use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).  You'll need to read the documentation for the directive as there are several options to how to make it work.

I've updated your example to make use of the ng-class directive and it is now making the button appear active when you click it.

I wouldn't recommend doing it exactly like this, especially the part about having your controller be responsible for CSS classes, but this is a good starting point for you to figure out the best way to do it in your situation.

**View**

```
<div>poiType is initialized to 0, so the first button should be selected
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl as ctrl" style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width:100%;">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <label ng-class="ctrl.class(ctrl.TYPE_POI)">
                <input type="radio" ng-value="ctrl.TYPE_POI" ng-model="ctrl.poiType" />POI</label>
            <label ng-class="ctrl.class(ctrl.TYPE_TRIP)">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" ng-value="ctrl.TYPE_TRIP" ng-model="ctrl.poiType" />itinerari</label>
            <label ng-class="ctrl.class(ctrl.TYPE_EVENT)">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" ng-value="ctrl.TYPE_EVENT" ng-model="ctrl.poiType" />eventi</label>
        </div>ctrl.poiType = {{ctrl.poiType}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('epoiApp', [])

    .controller('TodoCtrl', function () {
    this.poiType = 0; // first button should be selected

    this.TYPE_POI = 0;
    this.TYPE_TRIP = 1;
    this.TYPE_WAYPOINT = 2;
    this.TYPE_EVENT = 3;
    this.class = function (poiType) {
        if (poiType == this.poiType) {
            return 'btn btn-default active';
        } else {
            return 'btn btn-default';
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a link to the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r14618r7/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  poiType is initialized to 0, so the first button should be selected
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl"
       style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width:100%;">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" 
         data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio"  ng-value="TYPE_POI"
               ng-model="poiType" 
               ng-change="popup()"/>POI
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
           <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" 
                  ng-value="TYPE_TRIP ||
                            TYPE_WAYPOINT "
                  ng-model="poiType"  
                  ng-change="popup()"/>itinerari
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"  
                 ng-value="TYPE_EVENT"
                 ng-model="poiType" 
                 ng-change="popup()"/>eventi
        </label>    
     </div>         
   </div>         
</div>
```

You need to create a module for your angular app to refer to, here I called it myApp and declared it in the main div (usually, you want to do it in the body tag). Then you can create a controller and use the `scope` module to initialise data then use it as shown above.
Here is the js.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("TodoCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var that = $scope;

    $scope.poiType = 0;

    $scope.TYPE_POI = 0;
    $scope.TYPE_TRIP = 1;
    $scope.TYPE_WAYPOINT = 2;
    $scope.TYPE_EVENT = 3;

    $scope.popup = function () {
        alert(that.poiType);
    };
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manegan/awu36wb6/)

Comment: I 've updated my jsfillde ...  I am using controllers' attributes instead of scope variables. It should work thought...Anyway, the initial problem it's still there

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" 
             data-toggle="buttons">
```

`data-toggle="buttons"` is making radio buttons hidden. If you remove this, it will be shown

Comment: I know this answer is downvoted and irrelevant but it helped me :)